# Cannot convert from long[] to long

Tags: java, arrays, casting

Can anyone explain to me what's happening here and why? The compiler is not happy with the casting on the last line, it says 'Cannot convert from long[] to long':

```
    long[][] l2d;
    long[] l1d = {1,2,3};

    Object o = l1d;
    l2d = new long[3][3];
    l2d[0][0] = (long[])o;
```

Comment: `l2d[0] = (long[])o;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently *l2d* is a two-dimensional array, so *l2[0][0]* should be a **long value** here. However *l1d* is a simple **array**,so that object *o* is also a **array**.The type of *l2d[0][0]* and *o* don't match,although *o* has been cast to be a long array.

Answer (score 1):

l2d is two dimensional array of long. When you say 'l2d[0][0]' , you are addressing single cell in this 2D array , which of type long. You can only assign 'long' to it.

Answer (score 1):

Object o is an array, and you are trying to assign it to as an element in a 2 dimensional array. Hence long[] can't be converted to long. l2d[0][0] is expecting a long and you are trying to assign it long[]. Please try this-

```
long[][] l2d;
long[] l1d = {1,2,3};

Object o = l1d;
l2d = new long[3][3];
l2d[0] = (long[])o;
```